# Побудительное или вопросительное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

Каким является по цели высказывания предложение: "**Скажи, ты завтра придёшь**" и какой знак нужно ставить в конце?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это предложение вопросительное по цели высказывания, в конце предложения нужен знак вопроса. 
Первую часть этого предложения можно легко опустить без всякого ущерба для  смысла или заменить обращением, например. Целью высказывания является вопрос, а не побуждение.

Если бы придаточная часть содержала союз ЧТО, всё было бы по-другому. Предложение стало бы побудительным, так как главное предложение содержит побуждение, знак вопроса в конце предложения не нужен, т.к. исчезает вопросительная интонация во втором предложении (это придаточное изъяснительное). Ср.: Скажи, что ты завтра придёшь.